# The URI scheme of endpointOverride must not be null AWS S3 SDK in Android

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I am trying to use wasabi cloud storage using aws s3 sdk but I am getting The URI scheme of endpointOverride must not be null exception. Here is my code. How can I solve the issue?

```
private val AMAZON_S3_CLIENT: S3Client = S3Client.builder()
    .endpointOverride(URI(Config.SERVICE_END_POINT))
    .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
    .credentialsProvider(
        StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
            AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                Config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                Config.AWS_SECRET_KEY
            )
        )
    )
    .build()
```

Answer (score 6):

I just encountered the same exception, using AWS Java SDK 2 with DynamoDB.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: The URI scheme of endpointOverride must not be null
```

As the exception says the scheme in the URI of `endpointOverride` is missing.
I previously used `"dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"`.
Adding the scheme solved the problem.

```
"https://dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. you must prepend the endpoint with https://

We are using a Flink Kinesis Analytics app to read from a KDS and write to a Timestream instance.

In Flink when creating the required  TimestreamSink object in Java to write to Timestream there is a property that needs  bet set when using a VPC endpoint service.

TimestreamSinkConfig.builder().endpointOverride(endpointOverride)

initially I had endpointOverride as null when not using the VPC endpoint and that worked fine.

When we implemented the VPC endpoint with the endpoint

ingest-cell1.timestream.region.amazonaws.com

it did not work and it wasn't initially obvious why as the documentation didn't state that explicitly.

When I used  https://ingest-cell1.timestream.region.amazonaws.com
(where region is our AWS region and cell1 is the Timestream cell)
the Flink process was able to write to Timestream as expected.